# Tone.js audio filters not being heard

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, tone.js

I'm trying to add filter effects to an audio stream I have playing on my website. I'm able to connect the Tone.js library to the audio stream but I'm not hearing any changes in the audio stream playing on the website. I'm not seeing any errors in the console and I've tried adjusting the filter from 50 to 5000 but nothing seems to have any effect on the audio. Do I need to set up the `new Tone.Player()` to actually hear the audio? If so, how do you go about setting up the Player if there is no src for the existing audio element.

```
    $('#testBtn').click(async function () {
        const audioElement = document.getElementById('theAudioStream');
        const mediaElementSource = Tone.context.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
        const filter = new Tone.Filter(50, 'lowpass').toDestination();
        Tone.connect(mediaElementSource, filter);
        await Tone.start();
        console.log("Started?");
    });
```

The audio stream I'm trying to modify is set up from a JsSip call. The code to start the stream is as follows:

```
    var audioStream = document.getElementById('theAudioStream')

    //further down in code    

    currentSession.answer(options);
    if (currentSession.connection) {
        currentSession.connection.ontrack = function (e) {
          audioStream.srcObject = e.streams[0];
          audioStream.play();
        }
    }
```

I click the test button after the call has started so I know the audio stream is present before initializing the Tone.js Filters

Comment: I asked a similar question yesterday but that was more an issue with errors connecting Tone.js to the media stream. This has more to do with the filters not seeming to have any effect on the media stream.

Comment: I posted this to the question yesterday, but it probably makes more sense here. I'm having the same issue. See this codesandbox for non-working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jsintrostarter-forked-ftucj4?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @J.X.Weiss I saw your comment yesterday on the other thread. Yes this is very frustrating. I can make it work if the audio in the element is from a file. But my situation is the audio source is streaming from a webrtc call. Thanks for sharing your post I will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working solution:**
Removing the `audioStream.play()` from where the [**JsSIP**](https://jssip.net/) call is answered solves the issue. 
I don't know the exact reason why this solves the issue (it might even be a workaround) but after much trial and error this way allows the audio to be available to [**ToneJS**](https://tonejs.github.io/) for effecting.

Any other solutions are welcome.